# Given three vectors where $\textbf{p}\times \textbf{q}= \textbf{q} \times \textbf{r} = \textbf{r} \times \textbf{p}$, how to show that they sum to 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am trying to show that if $\textbf{p},\textbf{q},\textbf{r}$ are vectors such that $|\textbf{p} \times \textbf{q}| \neq 0$ and
$$\textbf{p} \times \textbf{q} = \textbf{q} \times \textbf{r} = \textbf{r} \times \textbf{p}$$

then $\textbf{p}+\textbf{q}+\textbf{r}=\textbf{0}$.

---

So far I have managed to show that $\textbf{p}+\textbf{q}$ is parallel to $\textbf{r}$ by showing

$$\textbf{q} \times \textbf{r} = \textbf{r} \times \textbf{p} \implies \textbf{q}\times \textbf{r} = -(\textbf{p}\times \textbf{r}) \implies (\textbf{p}\times \textbf{r}) + (\textbf{q}\times \textbf{r})= \textbf{0}$$

and hence

$$(\textbf{p} + \textbf{q}) \times \textbf{r}=\textbf{0}$$ so $\textbf{p} + \textbf{q}$ is parallel to **r**. However I can't see how you'd show that the scaling factor that takes one to the other is exactly $-1$. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $(\mathbf p + \mathbf q) \times \mathbf r = \mathbf 0$, we also have $(\mathbf p + \mathbf q + \mathbf r) \times \mathbf r = \mathbf 0$.

Similarly, we can prove that $(\mathbf p + \mathbf q + \mathbf r) \times \mathbf p = \mathbf 0$ and $(\mathbf p + \mathbf q + \mathbf r) \times \mathbf q = \mathbf 0$.

So $\mathbf p + \mathbf q + \mathbf r$ is parallel to all three of $\mathbf p, \mathbf q, \mathbf r$. But $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf q$ are not parallel to each other; therefore the only way that $\mathbf p + \mathbf q + \mathbf r$ can be parallel to both is if it's $\mathbf 0$.